# What does it mean "to blow out one's arm"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I've watched the episode of The Vampire Diaries today, and here's the question: what does it mean ***"to blow out one's arm"*** in the following context?

> So guess who came into the hospital for a shoulder arthroscopy this morning. Lady Whitmore, the girl from the bonfire, the one you miraculously saved from certain death and I can't figure out how. Turns out she was here on a tennis scholarship before she **blew out her arm** last year. Now she needs to get her cartilage cleaned out every 6 months.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means to sustain an injury (tendons, ligaments, cartilage) usually at the elbow. The injury comes from using the limb, not from an accident, e.g. not from a collision. Athletes in sports that involve heavy use of the arm  (such as tennis, or sports that involve throwing), often sustain shoulder injuries as well (e.g. at the rotator-cuff).

Comment: More commonly, regular folk *blow out their back* by twisting it funny or trying to lift something too heavy for them.

Comment: I've heard "I threw my back out" but never "I blew my back out". Sounds excruciating.

Comment: Sometimes a shoulder injury is still called 'blowing out the arm' especially when being very general.